# How could use Template Class for a container of container?

Tags: c++, class, oop, c++11, templates

I want to use my class with the template.
in main:

```
int main(void)
{
   HexAdapter<vector> foo;
   // maybe?
   // HexAdapter<vector<Cell>> foo;

   return 0;

}
```

I tried something like this

```
template <typename T>
class HexAdapter
{
public:
    HexAdapter();

private:
    T<T<Cell>> hexCells;

};
```

For the reason of this, Normally I used like this `vector<vector<Cell>> hexCells` But I want to work with all STL Containers with random access iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the `HexAdapter<std::vector>` syntax by relying on a *template template parameter*, i.e., a *template parameter* which is, in turn, a *class template* (or an alias template):

```
struct Cell { /* ... */ };

template<template<typename...> class Cont>
class HexAdapter {
   Cont<Cont<Cell>> hexCells;
   /* ... */
};
```

The template argument to the class template `HexAdapter` (i.e., the argument to the `Cont` parameter) must be a *class template* itself (e.g., `std::vector` or `std::deque`):

```
auto main() -> int {
   HexAdapter<std::vector> foo;
   HexAdapter<std::deque> bar;
}
```

Comment: A true hero <3 Thanks